# list/display/show both column names and column number together from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I imported a csv which gave me the following warning:

```
DtypeWarning: Columns (6,13,17,22,23,24,25,26,27,39,50,51,65,68) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
```

I can easily list the column names with

`list(df1)`

However, I'd like to easily list the column number along with it so I can see which part of the data has this issue. The format of the data doesn't really matter, I'm just looking at the output. There has to be some easy way of doing this, but I can't figure it out.

To be more clear, the first column in the df is called 'Stars', and the second is called 'Title' so in psuedocode I'd like to get this output

`list_columns_with_numbers(df1)`

`[(Stars, 0), (Title, 1)]`

The exact format doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

With `enumerate`:

```
print(list(enumerate(df))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 'Stars'), (1, 'Title')]
```

If you want them reversed (instead of number first):

```
>>> [x[::-1] for x in enumerate(df)]
[('Stars', 0), ('Title', 1)]
>>>
```